# How to add Text To Shapes in Blend Expressions 4?

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I am looking at the shapes available in Blend Expression 4 for my WP7 app I am making. I am a bit confused though how to add text to a shape.

How do I add text to a shape?

Comment: What are you actually after, text that follows the Path of a shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapes in Blend for WP7 are simply ... *[Shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.shapes.path%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)*.

All Expression Shapes inherits from Path, that inherit from `System.Windows.Shapes.Shape`. Shape is a base class for creating graphics. It supports only very basics properties such as fill, stroke, transform, ... you can not add text inside a shape because it's a pure-graphical object.

Hopefully for you, because they derive from `UIElement`, shape objects can be used inside panels and most WP controls. The `Canvas` panel is a particularly good choice for creating complex drawings because it supports absolute positioning of its child objects.

So, two examples can be

```
    <Grid>
        <es:RegularPolygon Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" InnerRadius="1" PointCount="6" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Width="100" />
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Hello" Foreground="black"/>
    </Grid>
```

or

```
    <Canvas Height="200" Width="200">
        <es:RegularPolygon Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" InnerRadius="1" PointCount="6" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Width="100" />
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="85" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Hello" Foreground="black"/>   
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: For some reason it seems like my MVVM light template does not have the 16 new(well from windows phone 7.5) shapes. If I open a non MVVM light one I do see all the shapes in the toolkit. I still can use the shapes in MVVM light toolkit but I need to copy in the xaml manually.

Comment: A problem with WP SDK version ?